# Ubuntu server and PHP $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp

Ive set up my own server with LAMP. Im using ubuntu server. When i try to find the user **ip** with:
 `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

it returns the server ip.

I have a static ip on my home router (eg, `58.83.2283.2`) which forwards all `HTTP` requests from port `80` to my laptop server (eg, `192.134.1`)

So `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is returning "`192.134.1`" and not the user ip.

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of using NAT.

Either run an HTTP proxy on the router (and use [`X-Forwarded-For`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) instead of `REMOTE_ADDR`) or give the machine running the HTTP server its own Internet facing IP address.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything?